# Updating ViewModel knockout with a nested loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

This may not be the completely ideal optimized way of accomplishing the task. I'm open for suggestions on any better ways. So far the loads work fine performancewise.

I have my knockout app working via ajax load. Inside the binding calls, I have a nested loop that includes a function that updates points based on a setting value.

When I attempt to add a new item, no errors are thrown, however the UI does not update and I can't seem to figure out why.

Here's a fiddle of what I'm trying to do.
http://jsfiddle.net/hjchvawr/2/

The addCombatant method does work, but for whatever reason the table will not rebind. You can see the added value in the VM json outputed to the console.

```
self.addCombatant = function(combatant){
        ko.utils.arrayForEach(self.divisions(), function(d){
            if(d.name() == combatant.division){
                d.combatants().push({name: combatant.name,
                            ID: combatant.ID,
                            swords:{points: 0, time:'none', kills: 0}
                            });
            }
       console.log(ko.toJSON(self.divisions));
    }
)}.bind(this);
```

EDIT:

I've applied some updates suggested below and added another list to sort. It binds and updates however, when I add a combatant, it only binds to one event and the sorting is off. If I can't use sortDivision(combatants, 'swords'), how do would I make the automatic sorting work? In this fiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/4Lhwerst/2/) I want the event sorted by kills, then time. Is it possible to get this multilevel sorting done client side without creating another observeableArray?

Comment: You know Knockout has a click binding, right?

Comment: Also, something goes wrong in your sorting function. This works: http://jsfiddle.net/4Lhwerst/

Comment: Yes about click binding. Not really the point though. I'm trying to isolate the update issue. My actual app has a lot more going on.

Comment: Dirk, I see what you did with the nested loop. Another case of me trying to use techniques form other languages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are pushing into the underlying combatants array and thus bypassing change tracking.  Either remove the parentheses (d.combatants.push) or call valueHasMutated after you are done.

You need either:

```
    if(d.name() == combatant.division){
        d.combatants.push({name: combatant.name,
                    ID: combatant.ID,
                    swords:{points: 0, time:'none', kills: 0}
                    });
    }
```

Or:

```
    if(d.name() == combatant.division){
        d.combatants().push({name: combatant.name,
                    ID: combatant.ID,
                    swords:{points: 0, time:'none', kills: 0}
                    });
        d.combatants.valueHasMutated();
    }
```

Comment: valueHasMutated didn't seem to do anything.

Comment: I edited my answer to be more specific. Did you try both of the above?

Comment: Neither will do anything, because combatants isn't the array being listed.

Comment: Actually, looking at the difference between the 1st and 2nd fiddles, you did follow my suggestion to eliminate the parentheses from d.combatant.  That is why the display updates when you add a combatant in fiddle 2.  Then you added a second question about sorting.  I answered your 1st question. If you needed additional help on a newly discovered behavior that became apparent after my answer helped you, you should mark my answer as correct and open a new question.

Comment: Tried both with my edit and it didn't do anything. Still need to sort the division on the bind. My old way maintained the sort if you changed some of the data. Yes adding the () to the combatants and having the valueHasMutated() does work. It was a combination of your answer and Dirk's comment that did it.

Comment: Again, sorting was not a part of your original question.  The question was about how to get the adds to show.

Comment: Point taken. It was brought up in some comments.

Comment: FWIW, a computed is the way to go on the sorting issue.

Comment: tangent question here... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30791543/sorting-nested-array-in-knockout

Answer (score 6):

This is the foreach binding in your table.

```
    <!-- ko foreach: $root.sortDivision(combatants, 'swords') -->
```

`sortDivision` is defined:

```
self.sortDivision = function (div, evt) {
    return div.sortBy(evt, 'time', 'asc').sortBy(evt, 'kills', 'desc');
};
```

Your `sortBy` function creates a new `observableArray`. That is not the same `observableArray` as is being pushed to.

```
ko.observableArray.fn.sortBy = function (evt, fld, direction) {
    var isdesc = direction && direction.toLowerCase() == 'desc';
    return ko.observableArray(this.sort(function (a, b) {
        a = ko.unwrap(evt ? a[evt][fld]() : a[fld]());
        b = ko.unwrap(evt ? b[evt][fld]() : b[fld]());
        return (a == b ? 0 : a < b ? -1 : 1) * (isdesc ? -1 : 1);
    }));
};
```

You should use `computed`s (or `pureComputed`s) for things that are a re-presentation or re-combination of data. Store any data item in one place.

Comment: I tried using a computed and it wasn't working at all. Not saying I won't go back to it though.

Comment: @Roy, I upvoted you because this is the correct approach for his 2nd question.